# Multiline string in slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I want to have a string of multiple lines in a slim template, like this:

```
style
  |  .card {
  |    height: 100px;
  |    text-align: center;
  |  }
```

Currently this works but it means I have to put `|` at the start of every line, which is really annoying.

Is there any way to have a multiline string in slim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://github.com/slim-template/slim#verbatim-text-

```
style
  |
    .card {
      height: 100px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

Or https://github.com/slim-template/slim#embedded-engines-markdown-

```
css:
  .card {
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```